# cordovaのmediaプラグイン1ファイルの再生時間全体の取得

Tags: monaca, cordova

cordovaのmediaプラグインを利用して音楽再生のできるものを作成しようとしていますが、mediaプラグインにおいて、1ファイルの再生時間全体の取得ってできるでしょうか。
　rangeを使って、100％のうち現在再生されているのは何％みたいなのを表示させたいと思っています。

Answer (score 1):

メディアプラグインの下記のメソッドを使用すると、全体の時間が分かります。

```
media.getDuration( )
```

参考情報
http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/reference/phonegap_34/ja/media/

Comment: オーディオファイルの再生時間を秒単位で返します。と書いてあるのですが、再生時間全体の取得ってできるのでしょうか…

Answer (score 1):

user7461 さんも書かれていますが、

演奏中における、現在の演奏位置（時間）は、media.getCurrentPosition() で取得できます。
全体の長さ（トラック全体の演奏時間）は、media.getDuration() で取得できます。

但し、当方がAndroid環境で確認した限りでは、new Media() の直後に getDuration() を呼び出しても -1 が返され、play() を実行後に getCurrentPosition() のコールバック内で実行すると正しい値が返されました（私の環境だけなのか、仕様なのかはわかりません。）

何パーセントか？を表示するとしたら、こんな感じでしょうか？

```
var totalTime = null;
var media = new Media(url, onSuccess, onError);

// ここで media.getDuration() とやると、-1 が返される？

media.play();

setInterval(function(){
    media.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        if( totalTime == null )
        {
            totalTime = media.getDuration();
        }
        var elapsed = (100*position/totalTime).toFixed(1) + "%";
        document.getElementById('elapsed').innerHTML = elapsed;
    }, function(e){
        console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
        document.getElementById('elapsed').innerHTML = "Error: " + e;
    });
}, 1000);
```